# Displaying white space when value is null for a view Oracle/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Is there was a way that I can display a empty string when a value is null?

I would rather that value be blank then having a (null) show up. I realized that NVL2(name, name, ' ') "name" does the trick almost. It works but it also changes the value to ' '. I am not trying to change null to ' ' only display it like that on the view. Is this possible?

Comment: Where does the value show up? SQL Developer, SQL*Plus, user application? Why would you want nulls to appear blank?

Comment: `I am not trying to change null to ' ' only display it like that on the view`: I don't understand this statement.  So do you want the value changed in the view, or not?  And I assume we are talking about a database view.

Comment: Besides the point, but you can use `nvl` or `coalesce` instead of `nvl2` in this case.  It's more straight-forward.

Comment: It is a view that being created from an xml. I am using oracle SQL developer. And yes in the view I want it changed but I dont actually want to change the value of null. I say that it is changing because I have another view that uses this view. It also checks for null. But if I have this NVL2 statement it doesnt pick up that the value is still null.

Comment: I want it to appear blank for personal preferneces. I just don't like seeing null everywhere. I just want it to be blank if null. #selfishreasons

Comment: Ok so more deatail on the problem. I am saying                    NVL2(q.BatchID, TO_CHAR(q.BatchID), ' ') "BatchID"                     That is what is messing it all up because when I check for the same null value I think it is messed up because I made my number type into a char type. Does that even happen or make sense on how Oracle does things??

Comment: Then change it to blank space wherever you query the view.  But the view itself can't possibly support both nulls and blank spaces at the same time.

Comment: You will want to use a "case when then else end" statement.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN name IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE name END
FROM
    test;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6191fb/5

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when the type is a Number... ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER Is the error and It means to me that yeah right you cant do this.

Comment: Here is the working example with integer its working in sqlfiddle I'm not sure why it would not work with oracle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9980c/1

Comment: If its not working for you try providing the exact query and schema of your table.

Comment: Hmmm... Yeah on your demo when I switch it to Oracle it gives me the same error I'm getting on my end. Maybe it's something that Oracle doesn't allow.

Comment: Hmm interesting! I don't know if you want to do this but I guess putting a zero is the only choice in case of oracle, as it can't display str where it has int. But I guess putting 0 will be misleading. Here is what can be done with 0 which you might have figured out by now.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9980c/6

Comment: Yeah I tried that out to see if I liked it but I didn't like the look. I just have to embrace it. If the type is not a varchar2 then I cant do what I want. That is in Oracle. Makes me sad to see all these nulls everywhere. If i find a solution down the road that displays a null value that is not a varchar2 as a blank string without actually changing the value of it in the view then I will post it. It really seems like you can't but once again I am new to this.